# Vercel ERROR: Error! Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my Nuxt.js site to Vercel but I get this error while deploying:

```
Error! Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in /vercel/path0/node_modules/@nuxtjs/vercel-builder/package.json
Error: Command "vercel build" exited with 1
```

I'm using [@nuxtjs/vercel-builder](https://github.com/nuxt/vercel-builder) module and this is my vercel.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "nuxt.config.js",
        "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Is there anything I could do to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use the latest version of the module? Mind sharing some Github repo or a [repro]?

Comment: @kissu Yes I do. I have the project in a private bitbucket repo. Do you have an account there?

Comment: Mind sharing it so?

Comment: Can I share it for your Bitbucket account?

Comment: Eh, I guess so. My username there is `kissu` too.

Comment: It seems that it requires an email address to invite. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Eh, create a Github repo and send it to me there so.

Comment: Sorry, took me a minute. I sent the invitation to your github account.

Comment: I am getting the same issue with a latest version of Vercel on Nuxt. 

I have deployed my latest working version of a site from a few weeks ago and I am getting the same issue, so it is not new changes to my codebase. 

Vercel CLI 24.1.1-canary.6 build (beta) If that makes any difference

Edit. Downgrading to Vercel 24.0.0 gives me the same build error. Something at Vercel's side?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! Have you came up with a workaround yet? Or do we just wait now?

Comment: I have the same problem. I did not make any changes to the packages. I think there is a problem on the vercel side. I created an issue on Github. https://github.com/nuxt/vercel-builder/issues/671